# How do I setup correctly continuous Integration on Windows Azure and Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

How to setup the properly the continuous integration when we have 1 solution (BuildDeploy.sln) and 2 cloud services (DataHora.ccproj and Maiuscula.ccproj):

When I try to run the default continuous deploy script created for visual studio online of maiuscula the cloud service is replaced by DataHora cloud service.

Seems that he gets only the datahora ccproj, because he is the first cloud project service of the solution.

To test my theory I create a custom entry in my configuration manager tha only builds maiusculo and change the Build Definition to get only **Any CPU|X_Maiusculo**

When I run the default build defition for maiusculo that was created by visual studio continuous integration I receive the following error:

> *Built $/ContinousDeployment/BuildDeploy/BuildDeploy.sln for target(s) DataHoraCloudService:Publish.*
>
> *C:\a\src\BuildDeploy\BuildDeploy.sln.metaproj: The target "DataHoraCloudService:Publish" does not exist in the project.*

So my question was: **How to setup my continous integration script to build and deploy only one project of my solution?**

Comment: Are you using the legacy XAML build? If so you should move to Team Build and us the Azure Cloud Service deployment template there.  You will need to modify it a bit to build both of your packages with unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one deployable code project in the solution then the default that's will not work. It was created as a quick deploy for good with some solutions.

If you instead switch to the default template and create a PowerShell that does your deployment of both services you can call It from the post-test location. This is a better way anyway as It is possible to debug outside of a build.